# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to solve this issue. I wanted to replace componentDidMount() with useEffect() and I got the error.

```
const requestData = group => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4996/getTagsFromWebsite", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(group),
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("request data", data);
        // debugger;
        setTagsData(data);
      });

  }, []);
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling `requestData` inside your react component? I had this same problem, your function name that you call inside the react component has to begin with `use`...something like `useRequestData`. It's called a custom hook. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook), the part about "whose name starts with 'use' "

Answer (score 1):

You could call your `useEffect()` directly inside your component and set your `requestData` like so:

```
function App(){
const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4996/getTagsFromWebsite", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(group),
    })
      .then(response => {
        return setRequestData(response.json());
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("request data", data);
        // debugger;
        setTagsData(data);
      });

  }, []);
}
```

If you would like this to be a hook, call it like so:

```
function useRequestData(route){
  const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState(null);
  const [tagsData, setTagsData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(route, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(group),
    })
      .then(response => {
        return setRequestData(response.json());
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("request data", data);
        // debugger;
        setTagsData(data);
      });
  }, []);
  // return [loading, data]
  return [!requestData, requestData, tagsData];
}

function App(){
  const [loading, data, err] =  
  useRequestData("http://localhost:4996/getTagsFromWebsite");
  return loading ? "loading..." : data.foobar;
}
```

Hope this helps,